# Viber API for C#

Tags: c#, viber

I've searched the internet, for viber's API. I haven't found anything. I'd like to know if there's anyone someone reversed engineered or something, that I can use on C#'s windows form. I'm trying to write a program to send bulk messages in bulk using viber on C#. Or if someone can do it, please, write me.

Comment: Surely just write C# to wrap their [RESTful API](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/)?

Comment: @NathanWhite thank you for your suggestion. Can I use the RESTful API on C#'s windows form?

Comment: If you're device is connected to the internet, C# can be used to communicate with a RESTful server. Absolutely!